# Как сделать toast с подтвержднеием?

Tags: android

Добрый день, возник вопрос как можно сделать что бы всплывающее сообщение было с подтверждением то есть с кнопкой OK ?

Comment: посмотрите, может быть вам подойдет `Snackbar`? https://material.google.com/components/snackbars-toasts.html

Comment: @Abrog Petrovich   Это не то (

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как правильный, поставив галку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Toast` не поддерживает `OnClick`, поэтому кнопка не будет работать. Решить Вашу задачу можно с помощью `Dialog'a` или `Snackbar'a`.

Comment: спасибо, точно Dialog.

Comment: @VargSieg Рад был помочь)

Comment: Еще добавлю, что следуя гайдлайнам Гугла, желательно вообще отказаться от использования Toast везде и использовать in-layout notifications (тот же самый Snackbar).

Answer (score 4):

`Toast` + `action` = `Snackbar`

```
Snackbar
  .make(parentLayout, R.string.snackbar_text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
  .setAction(R.string.snackbar_action, myOnClickListener)
  .show(); // Don’t forget to show!
```

[Взято отсюда](http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)